# ContentControl not aligning with text within a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I have a Hyperlink with various bindings that I have put into a DataTemplate to ensure the code isn't repeated. To use this I specify a ContentControl with a ContentTemplate. However, using a ContentControl inline with TextBlock text causes the link to be offset. I've got down to the following test case where this occurs:

```
<TextBlock>Text with a <ContentControl>Inline content control</ContentControl> in it.</TextBlock>
```

[image]

The only way I've found to get around this is to specify a negative margin on the ContentControl, but obviously this is not ideal as it will not work when the font size changes.

Comment: Would a ReadOnly RichTextBox make life easier? Sorry I don't have much experience doing inline controls just in TextBlock

Comment: You might try playing around with `TextBlock.BaselineOffset` attached property on your `ContentControl`, but I think it's not an elegant solution, if it solves the problem at all. I think you should consider defining a common `Style` for `Hyperlink` rather than wrapping it in a `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get a `ContentControl` to behave the same as an inline element, and the only way to get a `ContentControl` to stay inline with the text would be to modify padding/baseline etc. which can't respond to DPI changes and is obviously a bit of a hack.

I used Grx70's suggestion and instead moved my bindings into a style which I then set on the `Hyperlink` as needed:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomHyperlink" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
        <Setter Property="NavigateUri" Value="{Binding TheUri}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding TheCommand}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding NavigateUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>

<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        ...please <Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource CaseHyperlink}">view in browser</Hyperlink> and...
</TextBlock>
```